# React Native - How to reload colors based on Dark Mode and Light Mode

Tags: javascript, react-native, darkmode, appearance

We have been trying to implement dark mode in an old project, where we have some colors defined in a separate file and been used throughout the application something like mentioned below

```
import {Appearance} from "react-native";

const isDarkMode = (Appearance.getColorScheme() === 'dark')

const Color = {
    WHITE: '#FFFFFF',
    TRANSPARENT: 'transparent',
    THEMECOLOR: isDarkMode ? '#1A252F' : '#25A31D',
    THEMEBLACK: isDarkMode ? '#121B24' : '#252525',
    THEMEDARKGREEN: isDarkMode ? '#2F3F4D' : '#407F2C',
    THEMEWHITE: isDarkMode ? '#121B24' : '#FFFFFF',
    TXTGREETING: isDarkMode ? '#898989' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)',
    TXTWHITE: isDarkMode ? '#8A8A8A' : '#FFFFFF',
    TXTTHEME: isDarkMode ? '#676C69' : '#25A31D',
    TXTGREY: isDarkMode ? '#676C69' : '#9E9E9E',
    TXTDARKGREY: isDarkMode ? '#505050' : '#9E9E9E',
    TXTBLACK: isDarkMode ? '#676c69' : '#252525',
}

export default { Color };
```

It is used as shown below

```
import appColors from "common/colors";

export default StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flex:1,
        backgroundColor: appColors.Color.THEMECOLOR,
    }
});
```

We don't have any internal feature to switch to the Dark Mode inside the app, but it should work if changed from Device settings, which does work well but it requires killing the app and restarting.

It doesn't work when the app is running, though we have tried to infuse themes in `NavigationContainer`

```
import { NavigationContainer,DarkTheme,DefaultTheme } from "@react-navigation/native";
render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer theme={isDarkMode?DarkTheme:DefaultTheme}>
        <RootStackScreen screenProps={this.props} />
      </NavigationContainer>
    )
}
```

How to achieve this when the app is running and the Dark Mode is changed from device settings?

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Have you tried defining isDarkMode as a state and setting it in a useEffect?

Comment: Unrelated, but: for the line `const isDarkMode = (Appearance.getColorScheme() === 'dark') ? true : false`-- the condition check `Appearance.getColorScheme() === 'dark'` will return a boolean, so then putting it into a ternary is superfluous; it's like writing `const isDarkMode = true ? true : false;`.

Comment: IMO, the easiest thing to do here would be to define your colors using [CSS vars](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) assigned in a [`prefers-color-scheme`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme) media query or queries, and keeping React out of it entirely.

Comment: @AlexanderNied Ok, but I am looking for a solution for React Native to be specific, and we don't have much scope of working throughout the project, it will be a big ask to do so, as it is a complete project.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solve it with the code bellow:

```
const [colorScheme,setColorScheme] = useState(() => Appearance.getColorScheme());

const handleColorScheme = useCallback((theme) => {
  setColorScheme(theme.colorScheme);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  Appearance.addChangeListener(handleColorScheme);
  return () => {
    Appearance.removeChangeListener(handleColorScheme);
  };
}, [handleColorScheme]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Where did you put this code? Can you put a bit more detailed code?

Comment: put before your NavigationContainer render

Answer (score 1):

What Arthur does is correct. What you also could do for manual switching, is adding a button that writes ‘light’ and ‘dark’ to an ASync Storage and then read the values and load it before the render.

At least, that’s what I am doing! So even manual buttons are possible for sure. I have done so, because a big part of our userbase uses older phones.

Typically Arthurs code goes at the file that has the Navigation Stack inside it. If you have a one page app, you should load it at the home screen.